# How to get the package name of the client app from where the fill request is triggered

Tags: android, autofill

I’m currently developing an autofill service using the Autofill Framework available from Android Oreo. My question is could I get the package name of the client application from where the fill request is triggered?

I want to verify it with the credential data I own to ensure that my service injects confidential data only to the right app that need to be filled.

Answer (score 2):

Thank to Felipe Leme, I have the response. We can get the package name of client app from the AssistStructure.ViewNode with the method  getIdPackage(). We should also use PackageManager to check the signature of the package to avoid phishing.

Comment: Or you can also use getActivityComponent().getPackageName() on the AssistStruct object.